# Not able to get the children(s) height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending `div` to one of the parent. i require to calculate occupied size of the childrens. for that doing the loop to find the children height like this ;

```
this.clippings.children().each(function () {
    console.log($(this).outerHeight());
});
```

But I am getting always `0` so I decide to use the deferred:

```
$.when(that.clippings.children()).then(function () {
    that.clippings.children().each(function () {
        console.log($(this).outerHeight());
    });
});
```

But still i am getting same result. i think the `deferred` what i use this wrong. any one help me?

my app code :

```
onClipHandle : function (el,pNo,clipIndex) {
            //store selections
            var that = this;
            var avilableClass = el.attr('class').split(' ');
            var requiredClass = avilableClass[avilableClass.length-1];
            var selectedText =  $.trim($('.'+requiredClass).clone().children().remove().end().text());
            var elementClass = $('.'+requiredClass).attr('class');

            var classes = elementClass.replace(/textHighLight /g,'');

            var clipper = clipTemp.clone(false); //cloning

            // console.log(classes);

            clipper.addClass(classes);


            var collectClips = classes.split(' ');


            clipper.find('.text').append(clipIndex);
            var textBox = clipper.find('textarea');
            textBox.text(selectedText);

            setTimeout(function(){
                if($(textBox)[0].scrollHeight > 100 ) {
                    that.scrollHandler(textBox);
                } else {
                    textBox.height($(textBox)[0].scrollHeight);
                }
            },100); //only i am getting the height by delaying!


            clipper.on('click', 'a.clippingbin', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                textBox.slimScroll({destroy:true}); //removing scroll object
                var clip = $(e.currentTarget).parents('.clipping');
                $.event.trigger({type:'delete', clip : clipper, pagenum: pNo, clipIndex:clipIndex});
            });

            //add to side bar


            this.clippings.append(clipper); //appending
            $.event.trigger({type:'clipAppended', clip : clipper, pagenum: pNo, clipIndex:clipIndex }); //triggering
            $.event.trigger({type:'updateDocument',pagenum:pNo});


        }
```

once i hear the trigger `clipappended`, i am dong loop.

**UPDATE:**

```
this.clip.each(function(){
                console.log($(this)); //consoles
                console.log($(this).height()); //getting 0
            });
```

No idea..?

Comment: Can you please post your full code, including how you are appending the child elements. The deferred here is redundant as `children()` does not return a `$.promise`

Comment: `console.log(that.clippings.children().length);` -but i am getting length. before i go for loop.

Comment: When is `onClipHandle` firing? Is the DOM ready yet?

Comment: Have you tried .css('height')

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, yes. after dom loaded only i finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an javascript issue here, this is because of `css'. i updated my`css` from

```
div.clipping{
    clear: both;
    width: 92%;
}
```

to

```
div.clipping{
    clear: both;
    **overflow: auto;** - added
    width: 92%;

}
```

it works fine. thanks to all...!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a variable that takes the sum of all children height :

```
var occupiedHeight=0;
this.clippings.children()..each(function(index) { 
occupiedHeight+=$(this).height();
});
alert(occupiedHeight);
```

I think that should do it, **[here's a Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqanuLgp/1/)**.

Comment: It works fine, for me here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yqanuLgp/1/)**, maybe the problem is with `this.clippings.`??